# Battery voltage quickly drops when measured

Tags: battery-chemistry

I have a 9V battery that has around 9V when I first apply the probes for a multimeter. However, if I hold the probes on it for a few seconds, it starts dropping... about 0.10 V per second. And it just keeps going down.

I am guessing that this battery is shot but what is the mechanism for this? Why would it show a high voltage and then fall off instead of just showing low/no voltage from the beginning?

Is this because maybe the electrolyte is still able to produce power but there's something in the electrodes causing a super high resistance that just increases under load?

Comment: is it a moving coil meter or digital? I suspect a moving coil.

Comment: It's just a cheap digital multimeter

Comment: Did you test the DMM somewhere else? To me this seems like a faulty meter because it shouldn't draw a large current compared battery's self-discharging one. Any idea about the DMM's input impedance?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are right in believing that the battery "is shot."
To understand the "mechanism," think of the battery as being made up of 10 sections, each capable of 9V 1ma (10ma total).  When there is no load, if 9 of them are "shot" and one still good, the voltage would still be 9V but it can only provide 1ma.  If your load is 1ma or more, the voltage will drop very quickly. I hope this analogy is helpful.

Comment: You could check this by placing an series resistor of 20k. Your value would decrease more slowly.